# Faulty fretboard

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, fretboard

My acustic guitar ([Fender cd-140sce](https://shop.fender.com/en-US/acoustic-guitars/dreadnought/cd-140sce/0962704221.html)) is 2-years old, played an average of 1hour a day, and appears to have developped the following problem.

For several combinations of strings and positions on the fretboard, if you press the string on fret X, the string touches on the the fretboard on fret X+2. For example: the high E plays correctly, but if you try to play F you get a G note, playing F# gives you G, and playing G is the actual G.

I also notice the strings tend to vibrate on the fretboard if strum energetically, much more than before. I changed strings recently and it only changed the combinations of string/fret where the issue shows.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the neck has moved slightly. There needs to be a very slight bowing so the frets/fretwires are a little further away around the 12th fret than at the nut end. Usually, necks bend the opposite way, producing too much relief!

At the head of the guitar is a plastic plate, which when removed reveals the head of a long bolt which is known as the trussrod. It may be on your fender that the head is seen at the other end of the neck - inside the sound hole. Usually you need an Allen key - a hex key. By turning it to loosen the neck will unstraighten. A quarter/half turn at a time is recommended.

If you're unsure what to do, it's best left to an experienced person, as this can be a critical operation for the guitar

If this happened before the string change, and you're at concert pitch, it won't be the strings causing the problem..